# Glitch in the Gazebo Launch window

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-noetic, universal-robot

I am trying to launch the gazebo window, but am getting this glitch as it opens every time. I have attached the screenshot of it along with the question. Can someone tell me what the reason might be?[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include more information about your system and if this is temporary or continuous glitch.